# How can I make sun flare less distracting in post-processing?

Tags: lightroom, lens-flare

I took a photo against the sun and got some nasty orange artifacts:

[image]

Going black & white makes it less annoying, but I don't like the overall image. Are there any other post-processing techniques to mitigate it?

Comment: Additional advice for the future : make sure you use a hood and no "protective" filter when shooting - the hood reduces the likelihood of flares by simply shading the lens, and UV filter can make flares more like (additional glass for light to bounce off).

Comment: What software are you using? In Photoshop (or most other tools for that part), there is some type of ["clone stamp"-tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_tool) that could do the job.

Comment: "pre-processing" technique is using fill-flash, especially when shooting against the sun. It has nothing to do with flare, but filling scene with more details will distract from artifacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lens hood most definitely would have solved your problem. But, in the interest of helping you with *this* photo...

Your question is tagged Lightroom but it really needs to be tagged with Photoshop as well. I don't know of any solution in LR to solving the flare issue. I've done some cursory edits to your image, details below:
[image]

The orange spot flair on Gent's neck was removed with the patch tool - which you may be able to simulate in LR.

The flair on Gent's face was removed using a combo of:

- Layer set to Color and painting in from non-flaired skin hues
- Layer set to Hue and painting in from non-flaired skin hues
- Layer set to Overlay and painting in black to "burn" the flair area
- Some additional patch tooling around the edges
- Some patch tooling on Little One's hair

All of the above layers were Gaus. Blurred and opacity reduced to some degree to aid in the blending of the adjustment.

I stopped working on this before getting to Little One's hair and the back of the neck because, I think, you get the point.

The flair *can* be completely removed, or downplayed more...depends on how much you want to edit. Either way - I think you need to dive into Photoshop to meet your request.

Comment: @damluar As you've already accepted this answer, I assume you're good to go. If you need a deeper dive into exactly *how* the edits are done in a more tutorial like fashion, please post a new question tagged Photoshop and tag me in. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have with that image looks like it would have been solved with a simple lens hood. Depending on the lens you use you can find branded options and off-brand options (which are generally cheaper but normally of the same quality). They also have the added benefit of keeping your lend more protected in the event it's dropped. Some additional information related to lens hoods in regard to your issue:

> What good is the hood? The primary use of a lens hood is to prevent
>   light from hitting the front lens element from the sides - reducing
>   contrast and creating flare. Pictures taken with a lens hood installed
>   can have richer colors and deeper saturation.

[image]

[image]